# Ubuntu Desktop Freezes Randomly 18.04

Tags: 18.04, freeze

My PC freezes randomly. The background processes and everything is not operating. I am not able to open ctrl+alt+f4, seems to be completely frozen. Moreover I am not sure how to troubleshoot it either. It usually happens when I leave the PC on for long periods unattended. The thing is that it also doesn't reboot or start again, it just stays frozen.

At first I thought it was a hardware issue from my end but I can leave my PC open for 1 week+ on Windows and won't have any issues.

Really not sure how to troubleshoot it. Any advice?

Comment: Very possible that it's a GNOME extension. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. The go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and disable ALL extensions and see if the problem goes away. We'll re-enable them later.